# Backbone only recognizes routes beginning with Hashtags

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, url-routing

I'm riddling around with Backbone and Rails, but I'm coming across a problem where the router recognizes and accepts routes with hashtags (e.g. `localhost:3000/#posts`) and immediately changes the URL to back to the non-hashtag form (e.g. `localhost:3000/posts`). However, if I try to directly visit the non-hashtag form of the URL, rails will throw an error. Pushstate is on.

What could the issue here? Any help would be much appreciated.

blog.js.coffee

```
window.Blog =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  initialize: ->
    view = new Blog.Routers.Posts()
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:'/'})


$(document).ready ->
  Blog.initialize()
```

PostsRouter

```
routes:
  "posts" : "index"
  "posts/:id" : "show"
  "*path" : "index"
```

config/routes.rb

```
root to: "home#index"
```

Comment: What error rails is throwing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your server to route everything to your application (index.html most probably). I guess that could be missing. Say even if you have Backbone application turned off, your configuration on server side should be such that localhost:3000/posts lands in home page